# Should I put articles in the headlines of a CV?

Tags: articles, headline-english, headline-case

For example, here:

My contribution: Front-end development.

(**The**) Project: Our team realized the most popular news resource for a big city.

Comment: IMHO in a CV you need as few words as possible, you're not making a literary work you're writing a short document that carries a lot of information, so I think it's better without the definitive article "The".

Comment: What is the point of origin for the people receiving the CV? Different countries have different standards in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest no - generally accepted principles for CV's are to have as little 'filler' as possible, so headings, bullet points and list formatting is a typical way to present information in a content focused way.

In your example, the definite article adds nothing, so leave it out.